# set a tts message while making a call in android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a calling app where i want to speak a recorded message ( like call is up ) on both devices from user who is calling and the one who receives the call ,  is it possible to do so ? basically just to let both users that the call is up that's all , somehow in outgoing call i pass the that recorded message through to the call in the other device , Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't pipe audio into the call.  That takes permissions that you'd need to be privlidged to to.  You can play a TTS on the device your app is running on and hope its loud enough to be picked up by the mic.  Doing the call in speaker phone would help with that.  But it may not be clear on the other side that way.

Please note that if you're trying to call just to send a recorded message that's called a robocall and there are laws around doing that.  You have to follow do not call registries, etc.